# validar checkbox laravel livewire2

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire, livewire

Tengo el siguiente codigo

```
       <div class="w-100 d-flex justify-content-start">
            <h5 class="me-4">¿El requisito es?</h5>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline me-4 form-switch-xl">
                <input class="form-check-input @error('co.'.$k) is-invalid @enderror" type="checkbox" wire:model='co.{{ $k }}'>
                <label class="form-check-label">Conforme</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline me-4 form-switch-xl">
                <input class="form-check-input @error('nc.'.$k) is-invalid @enderror" type="checkbox" wire:model='nc.{{ $k }}'>
                <label class="form-check-label">No Conforme</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline me-4 form-switch-xl">
                <input class="form-check-input @error('ob.'.$k) is-invalid @enderror" type="checkbox" wire:model='ob.{{ $k }}'>
                <label class="form-check-label">Observación</label>
            </div>              
        </div>
```

Que renderiza parte de un formaulario que se carga dinamicamente,e ste funciona my bien pero no he podido validar estos campos ya que es obligatorio almenos tener uno en true.

la vista se ve asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El tema con la validacion es el siguiente: si o si uno de los 3 checkbox debe de estar selecionado ya sea conforme, no conforme o observacion, pero no debe dejar guardar si no se ha selecionado al menos uno.

Este es el codigo que uso para la validacion:

```
$this->validate([
            'auditado' => 'required',
            'evidencias.*' => 'mimes:pdf,doc,docx,xls,xls,jpg,jpeg,png',
            'observaciones.*' => 'required',
            'co.*' => 'required|boolean|exclude_if:nc.*,true|exclude_if:ob.*,true|accepted_if:co.*,true',
            'nc.*' => 'required|boolean|exclude_if:co.*,true|exclude_if:ob.*,true|accepted_if:nc.*,true',
            'ob.*' => 'required|boolean|exclude_if:nc.*,true|exclude_if:co.*,true|accepted_if:ob.*,true',
        ]);
```

Como se puede apreciar hay un campo auditado que es requerido (funciona bien), hay un campo evidencias que se usa pra subir archivos y este valida bien, tengo es el problema con los checkbox ya que no he logrado encontrar la forma de validarlos, si alguien conoce la validacion que se deba realizar mil gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Lo que podrías hacer es crear un `array` de opciones y validar si el arreglo contiene por lo menos un elemento.

Ejemplo `blade`:

**Nota:** Agregué un `var_export` después del botón para que se pueda ver lo que contiene `$options`.

```
<div>
  <form wire:submit.prevent="submitForm">
    <div class="w-100 d-flex justify-content-start">
      <h5 class="me-4">¿El requisito es?</h5>
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline me-4 form-switch-xl">
        <input type="checkbox" value="Conforme" wire:model="options">
        <label class="form-check-label">Conforme</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline me-4 form-switch-xl">
        <input type="checkbox" value="No Conforme" wire:model="options">
        <label class="form-check-label">No Conforme</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline me-4 form-switch-xl">
        <input type="checkbox" value="Observación" wire:model="options">
        <label class="form-check-label">Observación</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
    @error('options') <span class="text-danger error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    {{ var_export($options) }}
  </form>
</div>
```

Ejemplo componente `livewire`:

```
<?php

use Livewire\Component;

class LivewireComponent extends Component
{
    public $name = 'Laravel Playground';

    public $options = [];

    protected $rules = [
        'options' => 'array|min:1',
    ];

    protected $messages = [
        'options.min' => 'Se debe seleccionar por lo menos una opción',
    ];

    public function submitForm()
    {
        $this->validate();
        dd("Validado");
        $this->reset('options');
    }
  
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire-component');
    }
}
```

Al presionar el botón sin tener por lo menos una opción seleccionada se muestra lo siguiente:

[image: Muestra de ejemplo]

[Aquí](https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/b91a79b0-b535-4476-a03f-05d4c3e41d6c) te dejo un `laravel playground` con el ejemplo funcionando.

Comment: Hola sirve completamente pero ahora tengo otra duda solo se puede selecionar uno entonces al dar click a otro pues seleccionan los dos y deberia quitar el check del anterior y siempre ser uno solo selecionado.

Comment: Si siempre debe haber únicamente una opción seleccionada entonces utiliza un `radial input` en lugar de `checkboxes`.

Comment: Solo hice en la validacion 'options' => 'array|min:1|max:1' y esto me limita solo a tener una opcion selecionada :)